# Convert polar equation to rectangular when there is a floating constant.

Tags: polar-coordinates

I know how to convert a polar equation to a rectangular equation when it's in a form such as $$r=3\cos{\theta}$$
In that case, I would multiply both sides by $r$ to get
$$r^2=3r\cos{\theta}$$
and then substitute to get
$$x^2+y^2=3x$$
But what about when there's a floating constant, such as
$$r=3-3\cos{\theta}$$
If I try to use the same method, I get
$$r^2=3r-3r\cos{\theta}$$
and substitute to get
$$x^2+y^2=\pm3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3x$$
Would that be correct?

Comment: When you say you know how to convert, what is the result of the conversion?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. In this case, for example, you should share your method in the case where you know how to do it.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hopefully it's better now.

Comment: That's better. And yes, that's correct. I would write it as $(x^2+y^2+3x)^2 = 9(x^2+y^2)$ to avoid the $\pm$ and obtain a polynomial instead of an equation involving radicals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, except for a possible simplification. You can drop the negative version since
$$x^2+y^2=-3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3x$$
$$x^2+y^2=-3(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x)$$
The left side is always nonnegative. The right side will be negative unless two conditions are met.

1. $x\le0$
2. $|x|\ge\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

And since $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ and $y^2\ge0$, the second condition can only be true if $y=0$. This yields the solution point $(0,0)$, but the positive version already gives that solution point. This makes the final answer:
$$x^2+y^2=3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3x$$

The other option to get rid of the $\pm$ is to move the $3x$ to the left and then square both sides of the equation, giving:
$$(x^2+y^2+3x)^2=9(x^2+y^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have worked enough without the floating constant. Trick here  is to rope in $r$ by multiplication.

$$r=3-3\cos{\theta};~ r=1+2\sin{\theta}$$

$$r^2=3r-3r\cos{\theta};~ r^2=r+2 r\sin{\theta}$$

$$x^2+y^2=3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3 x ;~ x^2+y^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2 y ;$$
and so on..

Comment: What about the $\pm$?

Comment: There are two circles for $ r=3 \cos \theta,$ right? Likewise here also one sign for each cardioid included.

Comment: I'm graphing both and the $r=1+2\sin{\theta}$ doesn't match unless you add the $\pm$. Change your answer to $x^2+y^2=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+2y$ and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes, you have it. I've given you a hint. Before every $\sqrt{..}$ sign there stays  always implicitly at front a $\pm$ sign.

Comment: "Before every $\sqrt{..}$
 sign there stays always implicitly at front a ±
 sign." Perhaps that's a regional thing? Everywhere I've taught and learned math the $\sqrt{}$ symbol means the positive square root and $\pm\sqrt{x}$ is definitely different than $\sqrt{x}$.